# Add a level an extra level of nesting to JSONB from columns using to_jsonb

Tags: postgresql

In postgres you can convert a row to a JSONB using `to_jsonb` however I'd like to add an extra level of nesting. So given a table like

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  foo text,
  baz boolean
)
```

using `to_jsonb` produces

```
{
 "foo":"bar",
 "baz: false
}
```

but I'd like to transform the result to

```
{
 "foo": {
   "value" : "bar"
 }
 "baz": {
   "value": false
 }
}
```

for all top level fields without having to specify the field names.

Comment: You could do `SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, jsonb_object('value', value)) FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(*))`

Comment: `json_build_object` not `jsonb_object` but otherwise correct!

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi was super helpful. This is the answer (its `json_build_object` not `jsonb_object`)

```
SELECT
    (SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, json_build_object('value', value)) FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) as x(key,value)) as attrs
FROM test AS t;
```